# How to add SportsEvent schema Json-ld code inside PHP code WordPress

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, json-ld

I am a beginner trying to put together SportsEvent Schema code for my website. I have managed to get to this point. I created custom fields and mapped them to the Schema Properties. I can't seem to get past this point. I'm running into an error when I activate the plugin - `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /home/uhkcj8xz70dl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/football-schema/football_schema.php on line 21`

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Schema.org for Football
* Description: Add SportsEvent Schema.org in JSONld to site
* Plugin URI: 
* Author: Danstan
* Author URI: 
* Version: 1.0.0
* License: GPL2 or later
* License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

function addschema() //Function for Schema.org
{
global $post;
if (is_singular('matches')) { //only for post type matches
    $schema_sportsevent = array(
        '@context'  => "http://schema.org",
        '@type'     => "SportsEvent",
        'name' => get_the_title($post->ID);
        'description' => get_the_content($post->ID);
        'url' => get_permalink();
        'startDate' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'start_date' );
        'endDate'=> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'end_date' );
        'image'   => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);

        'competitor' => array(
            '@type' => "SportsTeam",
            'name'   => "Team A",
            'image'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'logo_left' );
        ),

        'competitor' => array(
            '@type' => "SportsTeam",
            'name'   => "Team B",
            'image'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'logo_right' );
        ),

        'location' => array(
            '@type' => "Place",
            'name'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'venue_name' );
            'address' => array(
            '@type' => "PostalAddress",
            'postalCode'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'zip_postal_code' );
            'streetAddress'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'street_address' );
            'addressLocality'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'locality_city' );
            'addressRegion'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'address_region' );
            'addressCountry'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'country' );
        )
        )
    );
    echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . json_encode($schema_sportsevent) . '</script>'; 
//encode schema for matches
}
endif;
}
add_action('wp_head', 'addschema'); //Add Schema to header
?>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing in some `;` where you need `,` because it's an array of values and you added an [endif](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) when you didn't need one. Try this.

```
function addschema() //Function for Schema.org
{
    global $post;
    if (is_singular('post')) { //only for post type matches
        $schema_sportsevent = array(
            '@context'  => "http://schema.org",
            '@type'     => "SportsEvent",
            'name' => get_the_title($post->ID),
            'description' => get_the_content($post->ID),
            'url' => get_permalink(),
            'startDate' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'start_date' ),
            'endDate'=> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'end_date' ),
            'image'   => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID),

            'competitor' => array(array(
                '@type' => "SportsTeam",
                'name'   => "Team A",
                'image'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'logo_left' )),
                array('@type' => "SportsTeam",
                'name'   => "Team B",
                'image'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'logo_left' ))
            ),


            'location' => array(
                '@type' => "Place",
                'name'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'venue_name' ),
                'address' => array(
                '@type' => "PostalAddress",
                'postalCode'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'zip_postal_code' ),
                'streetAddress'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'street_address' ),
                'addressLocality'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'locality_city' ),
                'addressRegion'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'address_region' ),
                'addressCountry'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'country' ),
            )
            )
        );
        echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . json_encode($schema_sportsevent) . '</script>'; 
    //encode schema for matches
    }
}
```

That should generate JSON like this. Although my post didn't have some of the post_meta to fill in some of the pieces.

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "SportsEvent",
  "name": "some stuff",
  "description": "",
  "url": "http://192.168.33.10/wordpress/blog/2019/11/28/some-stuff/",
  "startDate": [],
  "endDate": [],
  "image": false,
  "competitor": [
    {
      "@type": "SportsTeam",
      "name": "Team A",
      "image": []
    },
    {
      "@type": "SportsTeam",
      "name": "Team B",
      "image": []
    }
  ],
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": [],
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "postalCode": [],
      "streetAddress": [],
      "addressLocality": [],
      "addressRegion": [],
      "addressCountry": []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked but still one slight issue, the competitor property shows one one team, the `Team B` above to be particular. Unable to point out why the other entry is missing

Comment: They're the same thing so it uses the last value. You could change it to `competitor_1 `and `competitor_2` or change competitor to hold multiple values.

Comment: changing to `competitor_1` and `competitor_2` throws an error. It did not work even when I also tried to change competitor to hold multiple values like this `'competitor' => array(
            '@type' => "SportsTeam",
            'name'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'home_team' ),
            'image'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'logo_left' ),
            '@type' => "SportsTeam",
            'name'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'away_team' ),
            'image'   => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'logo_right' ),
        ),`

Comment: What error is thrown where? On my end the PHP works. The JSON validates.

Comment: The error shown is `property competitor_1 is not recognized by Google for an object of type SportsEvent.` Looking for something along the lines of this shorturl.at/acnPS where it shows two competitors for SportsEvent. That's the only issue otherwise the rest of the JSON is okay. Also, there is homeTeam and awayTeam entries but I was wondering if using that would have any impact on matches played on neutral grounds so I wanted to stick with competition.

Comment: I see the use of this `[]` to wrap the competition property. Is it what we might be lacking, I can't seem to get past this.

Comment: I believe the updated answer will validate and, if not, you probably need to ask a different question around schema construction.

Comment: It doesn't validate. I have posted a question on this specific area. Thanks for the input.

Comment: When I run it through the validator at https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool the team portions are clean. There are other issues. You seeing something different?

Comment: No. If you may, please look at how the competitor here shorturl.at/acnPS shows two of them. In our case it just shows the second team, leaving out the home team in this case. The rest of the JSONld is validating well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208726/discussion-between-tom-woodward-and-danstan-ongubo).